# jQuery ui autocomplete cache xml source

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, caching, autocomplete

I'm using a remote XML source. Can someone point me in the right direction to cache this document?

Thanks

Comment: Explain what you mean by *cache*. How long should the cache persist? For the lifetime of a single page in a single browser? Across loads of the page?  Also - Show your code. the solution could be as simple as setting a variable in javascript to the content you get back from the XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: It should check the headers to see if the page has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  when you use ajax to call up the data source you can tell it whether or not to cache the data source.

Comment: It says default behavior is true. Since it is not caching for me I was assuming that it does not apply to XML source

Comment: Does the URL to your xml resource have a querystring?  Some browsers will not cache content if it has a querystring.

Comment: The XML document is served through a query string:                    ?prod_id=#####&form_id=#####

Comment: Looks like that is the problem I am having. Thanks Josh

Comment: Yeah, that would be the issue you are seeing.  :)  Actually, I use that "feature" to version my javascript files so I can ensure the user always has the latest copy.  It's especially helpful in development.

Answer (score 1):

I use the jquery ajax function all the time its very useful, explain exactly what you're trying too do though

Comment: I did. My source is a remote xml document. I want to cache that document so that the user does not need to re-download the entire XML file every time they visit the site.